# Using React "useState", when a value updates within an object, this re-renders everything attached to the state, even when some values didn't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

**What am I trying to do?**

Stop re-renders when adjusting the state of an object when I update only one value and the other values remain intact.

**What is the code that currently tries to do that?**

The front-end component rendering the info:

```
export default function ReactComponent() {
  const [characterState, setCharacterState] = useState(data.character);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("/character/read");
    socket.on("/character/read", function (data) {
      if (data.status === "SUCCESS") {
        setCharacterState(data);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      socket.off("/character/read");
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Name: {characterState.name}
      Stand: {characterState.stand}
      Status: {characterState.status}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The back-end `.json` info as "data" and also what is saved onto `characterInfo` by `setCharacterInfo`:

```
{
  status: "SUCCESS"
  character: {name: "Dio", stand: "The World", status: "Alive"};
}
```

**What do I expect the result to be?**

If the back-end sends something new on the "/character/read", say:

```
// Status is now "Dead".

{
  status: "SUCCESS"
  character: {name: "Dio", stand: "The World", status: "Dead"};
}
```

I expect in the React function to only re-render the status.

**What is the actual result?**

The whole state is re-rendered (visible to see of the values adjusting), despite the other values in the object not updating.

**What I think the problem could be?**

I think it has to do with with "useState", that "useState" doesn't care about if there's some changed, all changed, or no changed values, "useState" will always re-render whatever it's given. I'm thinking a possible solution would be making 3 separate states for "characterName", "characterStand", and "characterStatus", but seeking if there's another alternative to the tried attempt of 1 state only.

**EDIT:**

I failed to relay what I was trying to achieve, but what Sajeeb said was what I was ultimately looking for.

If the attribute, in this case "characterState.status" changes, I expect a re-render on "characterState.status" and *not on "characterState.name" nor "characterState.stand"*. Due to React's default behavior, all of these attributes under 1 state will cause each of them to re-render because the state "characterState" itself was updated.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: IF a state value changed then the whole component will be re-rendered. This is the default behaviour of React.

Comment: Even if you split it up to multiple `useStates` in one component, it'll still re-render the whole component

Answer (score 1):

You are using **1 state** variable which stores a **dictionary of 3 values**, not 3 different state variables. So when you call the state update function, it will change that 1 state which is a dictionary, instead of changing only a single property of the state variable.

The only solution is to, as you are already onto, create separate state variables.

Cheerio!

Edit: It is to be noticed that despite splitting the state variables, the entire component will still re-render every time a state changes, so 3 different state variables won't prevent entire component refreshing. I suggest you write a different component to display name, stand, status separately so that when the props passed to a particular child component changes (say Status), only that component refreshes.

Edit: I'm still laughing at the JoJo reference lol.

Comment: Since he does one API call, it would not make sense to split it into 3 separate components and do 3 API calls. This means that it's better off to have the values in one component. Even if there are three separate `useStates ` when one updates, the whole component will update. It is just more performant and makes more sense in this case to simply leave it as is.

Comment: True. I don't really understand what OP wishes to achieve. I think I've got a new suggestion, to create different components to display the {name, stand, status}. Let me edit my answer real quick.

Comment: Even if you split it into 3 components, what did you achieve? More complexity at no gain.  If you try to request the 3  values separately, now you have three `useStates` to manage, and you just did 3 API calls.  Instead of 1 API call, 1 component, 1 `useState` and cleaner code.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know what OP is trying to achieve, or what their problem is with all three values refreshing even though only 1 value is changing. OP asked for a specific workaround, I provided something. I decided to let OP work with both choices to learn the pros and cons of both methods.

Comment: By the way, if you have three components in one parent component even if just one `useState` is updated, or just one prop is changed, it will still re-render everything: the parent and all the child components.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend you to leave it as is.

Reasoning:

**What you now have:**

- 1 API call
- 1 Component
- 1 One state to manage

Since your data stored in `characterState` is so small, it really would not make any sense to break it up or worry about a possible re-render.

In any other case, you'll end up with a less clean and less performant code.

For instance, if you try to break it up into three `useState`s in one component, you have now 3 states to manage, and you haven't solved your issues with the re-renders.

If you  used three different components for the states, **you would have**:

- 3 API calls
- 3 Components
- 3 States to manage

And less clean code.

All for solving a problem that isn't really a problem

In the case provided by you, I would most certainly recommend leaving it as is.

*Unless you have something very specific reason why this would not work well.*